# Create implicit cast for enum value

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I've created my own MessageBox with my own enum MessageBoxButton :

```
public enum MyMessageBoxButton
{
    OK = MessageBoxButton.OK,
    OKCancel = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,
    YesNoCancel = MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel,
    YesNo = MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
    NowLaterCancel = 5,
}
```

As you can see, it's like System.Windows.MessageBoxButton with 1 value more.

For my class MyMessageBox, I have the function :

```
public static MessageBoxResult Show(String caption, String message, MyMessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon)
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to call `Show` with `MessageBoxButton` and implicitly cast the value to a `MyMessageBoxButton` ?

Comment: Can I suggest a change to your solution? You have a enum that lists the possible combinations of buttons. However you have created a single value for multiple variations. This is inflexible. I would suggest the following: None = 0, OK = 1, Yes = 2, No = 4, Cancel = 8, Later = 16 this way you can use a bitwise operation to workout which buttons are available. 1 + 8 = 9 (OK, Cancel) 2 + 4 = 6 (Yes, No) etc

Comment: Have you tried `switch/case`? What you call *casting* is in fact *mapping*, yet you have to do something for that extra value, aren't you?

Comment: I've try solution provide by itsme86 and it works. Like I don't undestand with I should use a `try/catch`

Comment: Is this wpf? Because in winforms it would be `MessageBoxButtons` not `MessageBoxButton`

Comment: @RossMiller - This is the same  enum as `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons` except he has renamed the last item from `RetryCancel` to `NowLaterCancel` and removed `AbortRetryCancel`. The design works, because it allows a user to pass the desired button configuration to the message box in one argument.

Comment: Should work i fyou just make parameter of tyoe `int`

Comment: @A.Pissicat - did the mapping work ok when user passes a value you don't have a matching value for (i.e. `MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore`)?

Comment: @RufusL I forgot to precise, i'm working on WPF. Actually I copied all the values in `MessageBoxButton`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a converter method that converts a `MessageBoxButtons` to a `MyMessageBoxButton`, create an overload of your `Show` method that takes a `MessageBoxButtons`, and then in that method you would do the conversion and call your existing `Show` method.

Since you don't have matching enum values for all items (like `AbortRetryIgnore`), you will have to decide which button combination to show if someone selects one of those:

```
public static MyMessageBoxButton ConvertToMyMessageBoxButton(MessageBoxButtons input)
{
    MyMessageBoxButton result;

    switch (input)
    {
        case MessageBoxButtons.OK:
            result = MyMessageBoxButton.OK;
            break;
        case MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel:
            result = MyMessageBoxButton.OKCancel;
            break;
        case MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel:
            result = MyMessageBoxButton.NowLaterCancel;
            break;
        case MessageBoxButtons.YesNo:
            result = MyMessageBoxButton.YesNo;
            break;
        case MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel:
            result = MyMessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel;
            break;
        default:
            // AbortRetryIgnore will fall through to this
            result = MyMessageBoxButton.OKCancel;
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you would use the `Convert` method in an overload of your `Show` method, to do the conversion and call your original `Show`:

```
public static MessageBoxResult Show(String caption, String message, 
    MessageBoxButtons button, MessageBoxImage icon)
{
    return Show(caption, message, ConvertToMyMessageBoxButton(button), icon);
}
```

Comment: Actually it works with a cast but I will change to your solution, more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an overload for `Show()` that takes a `MessageBoxButton` and casts it:

```
public static MessageBoxResult Show(String caption, String message, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon)
{
    return Show(caption, message, (MyMessageBoxButton)(int)button, icon);
}
```

Not sure if the first cast to `int` is necessary. Try it without first.

Note that this relies on the values for both enums to match. For example, MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel must be 3 like it is for MyMessageBoxButton.

Comment: Cast is required. Since C# does not allow implicit conversion

Comment: This is so error-prone. I would really provide a method that returns a `MyMessageBoxButton` for a given `MessageBoxButton` that  uses a `switch...case`.

Comment: I've try with a new show method : `return Show(caption, message, (MessageBoxSVButton)button, icon);` and it seems to work. I don't understand what I should do with a `switch/case`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't see how that's a *lot* better. If .NET changes the enum values on you then your mapping will still silently break. You're either going to have to change the mapping or enum. Choose your poison. I don't really like the idea at all. I was just trying to give a solution.

Comment: I modified my definition of `MyMessageBoxButton`, to be sure to cast correct value.

Comment: @itsme86: why that? It would work if the values change but the names remain the same